# How can I design rooms and encounters for a "natural" dungeon?

Tags: dnd-4e, dungeon-design

The next dungeon will take my group to the inside of a giant tree where an evil parasite has its nest. The miasma it produces is poisoning the water and it about to cause the flower from which baby pixies would be born to wither and die.

Although I can see how my evil humans have added puzzles and such to the inside of a giant, I have never designed an encounter with rooms that were not 4x4 or one that had non-human hazards. This made some of my older encounters as a GM quite boring.

The thing is, how are dungeons that aren't man-made usually designed? Remember that the idea is to explore and find the nest of the parasite.

Comment: Can you give more details about this parasite? how is its body shaped? how does it moves? how intelligent is it? does it have any manner of tools or spells to adapt the tree to its needs? is this a solitary creature or a nest/village of things?

Comment: The Parasite is a grotesque creature similar to a slug, but longer, with insect-like legs (centipede) and a skull covering its head. It lives in tunnels made of some sort of artificial tissue and goo on the deepest part of the Tree. It's as intelligent as an alligator and lays its eggs on the nest. The gas it produces poisons the roots and thus, the water of the river that feeds the tree and the Pixie Village.

Comment: This question immediately brought to mind the Deku Tree dungeon in Zelda: Ocarina of Time...

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking here. Do you want encounter building advice? Advice on making maps with non-square rooms? How to design encounters in non-square rooms? (Why, what difficulty are you having with that?) Are you asking for advice on how to structure the dungeon overall? These are *all* different questions, and I can't tell which you're asking from how you wrote this. (And if you want all of those: that's too many questions in one post; split it up.)

Comment: I think it'd be better to say I'm asking what kind of progression can a non-human built dungeon can have. I mean, human dungeons usually require the players to solve puzzles, look for keys, etc, but I don't see a non-human built dungeon having those, specially since it's inside of a tree.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine the parasite boring through the tree slowly, like a wig or a cicada over years (or decades or even centuries). It would have left a perfectly rounded tunnel that spirals gently down. The tunnel would have gotten larger over time as the parasite grew. For rooms you could add offshoots that are roughly spherical and represent either spots where the parasite stopped to lay eggs (minion encounter!) or spots where other smaller creatures have burrowed in (these could even have smaller crawl-space exits to the surface). There could also be round-abouts or diversions where the parasite found the wood too tough to chew through. Perhaps there are veins of sap running perpendicular to the tunnel that would provide pitfalls or chutes to reach other dungeon levels.

I love your idea, by the way. I hope your campaign comes off well and that your players love your setting.

Answer (score 2):

That sound pretty fun! :D

### Base Structure

What material are the walls and floor made of? Does the parasite leave bare wood behind or does it it leave some sort of coating behind?

eg: The Zerg in Starcraft leave behind The Creep. Zerg move faster over the substance than they do otherwise. In your campaign, if the parasite has multiple stages of development, the "egg" could stay in for the nutrients, the "larva" could dig/swim through the substance and attack from hiding, while the "adult" could walk faster on it (or non-parasite characters who walk on it could walk at half-speed).

The design of the base should be logical to the parasites' needs, and take into account the stages of development. If the "larvae" aren't allowed to access some areas those areas should be restricted by abilities that the adults possess and larvae do not, such as flight or climbing. Also, if every stage can fly or climb, there isn't any reason to keep the entrance(s) at ground level; a tower with no stairway, for example.

### Non-human but intelligent

The parasite would be an intelligent insect or have some stage of development with mental capacity. In this case the inner design of the nest should follow a logical pattern for the parasite but also a logical pattern for any possible allies/slaves of the colony, like other monstrous insects or animals. If only the highest stages are intelligent, the areas where they reside would likely have extra protections (such as traps).

### Non-human & non-intelligent

The pattern should be simple and pretty optimized for the parasite. It should follow a pattern of an existing nest (with brooding room, queen room, etc.) and add some "traps" which would otherwise be normal features of the colony. In the brooding room, for example, a simple trap could be pupal cells under the floor. When the PC walks over the cell, he breaks the seal and falls into a "pit trap" with a angry/hungry parasite at the bottom. If the insect can fly, we could imagine a large pit between two ridges with no possibility to pass except with a flying ability, which could motivate your group to capture some parasites to get through.

An insect/parasite dungeon concept like this looks fun. It's an idea I've never had!